# MDX query to count number of rows that match a certain condition (newest row for each question, client group)

Tags: mdx

I have the following fact table:

```
response_history_id     client_id       question_id     answer
1                       1               2               24
2                       1               2               27
3                       1               3               12
4                       1               2               43
5                       2               2               39
```

It holds history of client answers to some questions. The largest response_history_id for each client_id,question_id combination is the latest answer for that question and client.

What I want to do is **to count the number of clients whose *latest answer* falls within a specific range**

I have some dimensions:

```
question                associated with question_id  
client                  associated with client_id  
response_history_id     associated with response_history_id  
range                   associated with answer. 0-20 low, 20-40 = medium, >40 is high
```

and some measures:

```
max_history_id as max(response_history_id)
clients_count  as disticnt count(client_id)
```

Now, I want to group only the latest answers by range:

```
select
[ranges].members on 0,
{[Measures].[clients_count]} on 1
from (select [question].[All].[2] on 1 from [Cube])
```

What I get is:

```
Measures                All     low     medium  high
clients_count           2       0       2       1
```

But what I wanted (and I can't get) is the calculation based on the latest answer:

```
Measures                All     low     medium  high
clients_count           2       0       1       1
```

I understand why my query doesn't give me the desired result, it's more for demonstration purpose. But I have tried a lot of more complex MDX queries and still couldn't get any good result.

Also, I can't generate a static view from my fact table because later on I would like to limit the search by another column in fact table which is timestamp, my queries must eventually be able to get _the number of clients whose latest answer to a question before a given timestamp falls within a specific range.

Can anyone help me with this please? 
I can define other dimensions and measures and I am using iccube.